# Interpolação de números decimais no R

Tags: r

Olá!
Eu tenho uma sequência de números quebrados (ex. 191.1, 191.48, 191.87) e queria transformar esses números em inteiros (todos 191. virar 191). É possível fazer isso no R ou no excel? Não consigo fazer uma função simples porque não existe uma sequência exata dos números (as vezes são 3 números quebrados, as vezes são só 2).
Obrigada!

Answer (score 3):

No R, pode se usar a função **trunc**

```
> trunc(191.1)
#[1] 191
> trunc(191.48)
#[1] 191
> trunc(191.8755)
#[1] 191
```

No Excel a função **Truncar**

```
= TRUNCAR(191,8755;0)
```

**Conjunto de Dados**

```
   > dados
       wavelength spectra
#1      190.10  -13.10
#2      190.48  -10.30
#3      190.87   -3.55
#4      191.25   -0.82
#5      191.63   -4.14
#6      192.02   -1.06
#7      192.40    5.21
#8      192.78   12.23
#9      193.17   10.88
#10     193.55    5.95
#11     193.93    7.80
#12     194.31   13.10
#13     194.70   10.88
```

Média de cada **spectra** segundo **wavelength**

```
library(dplyr)
dados %>% group_by(trunc(wavelength)) %>%
  summarise(media_spectra = mean(spectra))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  `trunc(wavelength)` media_spectra
#                <dbl>         <dbl>
#1                 190         -8.98
#2                 191         -2.48
#3                 192          5.46
#4                 193          8.21
#5                 194         12.0
```

Comment: Muito obrigada! Deu certo assim! Mas, e se a cada número fracionado eu tiver um número associado a ele (x, y) e eu quero que esse y também seja interpolado. Pra ficar mais claro, eu tenho comprimento de onda x espectro refletido. O comprimento de onda que esta fracionado, mas me interessam os valores inteiros. Então, eu preciso trabalhar com a media dos espectros refletidos referentes a cada interpolacao. É possível com essa mesma função?

Comment: Ficará mais fácil te ajudar se você, postar uma amostra ou um exemplo minimamente reproduzível do seu conjunto de dados. Se o seu bd não for muito grande, edite o seu poste anterior, colocando uma amostra, para isso pode-se usar o comando `dput(dados)`, assim ficará mais fácil compreender com qual estrutura estamos lidando.

Comment: Claro! Aqui está uma parte dos meus dados 
structure(list(wavelength = c(190.1, 190.48, 190.87, 191.25, 
191.63, 192.02, 192.4, 192.78, 193.17, 193.55, 193.93, 194.31, 
194.7), spectra = c(-13.1, -10.3, -3.55, -0.82, -4.14, -1.06, 
5.21, 12.23, 10.88, 5.95, 7.8, 13.1, 10.88)), row.names = c(NA, 
-13L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
Então, para cada valor de x (wavelength) quero transformar os numeros fracionados em inteiros e fazer a media desses numeros e dos respectivos valores de y (spectra).

Comment: @LaísMoreira tente assim: `apply(trunc(dados), 2, mean)`

Comment: Mas aí eu vou fazer a média de tudo, não? A ideia é fazer a media de todos os x = 190 e de todos y respectivos.

Comment: Seria então uma coluna pela outra correto? Então faça assim: `trunc(dados$wavelength)/trunc(dados$spectra)`

Comment: Ainda não deu... Eu não estou sabendo te explicar. 
Vou tentar explicar de outra forma - para cada wavelength existe um valor de spectra. Mas não me interessam valores fracionados de wavelength, por isso eu quero interpolar as frações. Com isso, eu terei várias wavelengths iguais. A ideia é eu então fazer a média dos spectras para cada wavelength inteira. Assim, eu terei uma coluna com wavelength e uma coluna com spectra. Faz sentido? Desculpe a enrolação nessa pergunta.

Comment: Creio que compreendi agora o que você quer, vou editar a resposta dada anteriormente, veja se é exatamente isso mesmo.

Comment: Deu certo!! Valeu demais!!

Answer (score 2):

Se preferir, arredonde esses números para o inteiro mais próximo com a função `round`:

```
x<-c(191.1, 191.48, 191.87)
x
#[1] 191.10 191.48 191.87

round(x,0) # onde 0 é o número de casas decimais
#[1] 191 191 192
```